# String to Date with current Time

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert date entered int String to DateTime type

I use the following

```
  DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateText);
```

Let say the dateText=5/20/2014 DateTime date become 5/20/2014 and 12:00:00 AM. I I want the current time of the day to be picked up instead of 12:00:00 AM.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you do:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateText);
```

Then do:

```
DateTime fullDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
```

...or as suggested by Ulugbek Umirov:

```
DateTime fullDate = date.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: It would be easier to do: `DateTime fullDate = date.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateText + " " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: Might want to at least chunk a space in there